# GET me/contacts returns 'Resource could not be discovered'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using this tutorial: [Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a React single-page app (SPA) using auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react) to my registered app on in Azure Active Directory

I want to get contacts from my Outlook Contacts so I added  the `Contacts.Read` delegated permission.

After logging in (after I consent to the permission to read contacts) I can successfully issue a GET call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` using the auth token.

When I use the same to token to call the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts` endpoint, I get an `HTTP 404` error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-03-23T14:50:53",
            "request-id": "d4e9c0cc-06f4-4c2a-9969-7889a968f5ba",
            "client-request-id": "d4e9c0cc-06f4-4c2a-9969-7889a968f5ba"
        }
    }
}
```

I can use Graph Explorer to retrieve my contacts, but when using my own token I get above error.

I'm not sure why this happen, am I miss something?

[image: Permission Scopes]

Comment: could you pls [decode the token](https://jwt.io) `using authorization code flow to get token` and check the `scp` claim?

Comment: Yes I checked and scp claim contained the contacts.read. But now I found [@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) and modify my code base on example [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-reactspa) I can now get my contacts at https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts

Comment: Does the user have a mailbox provisioned?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Yes I have a mailbox, as I mentioned above it work ok with graph explorer. But I have solved the problem by add @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Please add the steps you used to solve it as an answer. Aside from giving you a few extra reputation points, it will help folks who run into this issue in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I agree with @Nam Nguyen, to resolve the error make use of **`@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client`** in the code.

Install and import the **module** by using below command:

```js
npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client
import @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client
```

Modify the **code** like below to fetch the contacts:

```js
export async function getUser(authProvider: AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider): Promise<User> { ensureClient(authProvider);  

const user: User = await graphClient!.api('/me')  
.select('displayName, mail, mailboxSettings, userPrincipalName')  
.get();  
return user;  

var response: PageCollection = await graphclient!  
.api('/me/contacts')  
.get();
```

[image]

For more in detail, refer the **GitHub Blog** by jasonjoh : [GitHub - This sample demonstrates how to use the Microsoft Graph JavaScript SDK to access data.](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-reactspa)

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment in Postman and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD SPA Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

Now, I generated access token using PKCE flow like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

By using the above generated access token, **I am able fetch the contacts** like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
```

[image]